# Jquery : Function to autoscroll the page on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a jquery function that will scroll the page (from where the user currently is) by 100 pixels. Please note, this function does not scroll from the top, it scrolls from the current position.
so far i have :

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+100);
  });
 </script>
```

It doesn't do anything.

Comment: try it on $(window).load instead.

Comment: Try using `document` instead. Also, is your document actually longer than the viewport?

Comment: dont worry about where the function is running, I have that sorted. Its the actual function thats the problem, I can't get the scroll to work

Comment: @Asad, check your math. document.ready is before window.load. Read some documentation.

Comment: @HristoYankov you're absolutely right!

Comment: @HristoYankov Oh right, the window isn't completely loaded until the document is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @HirstoYankov for partly helping.

Below is the code that fixed it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function () {
  $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+1);
    });
</script>
```

Its important to use `$(window).load` and not `$(document).ready`

Comment: I am glad I 'partly' helped :) "try it on $(window).load instead. – Hristo Yankov 44 mins ago "